# Correcting vector with respect to a linearized vector (Matlab)

Tags: matlab

Consider a time series which is "incomplete", i.e, some timestamps are missing in the time vector:

```
t=[0 3 6 9 12 21 24]; % here the time step is dt=3
```

Consider that there is a measured data vector which correspond to this time series

```
x=[1 2 3 4 5 20 22];
```

How do I change `x` and `t` such both sequences will linear in time, and in the locations where there is no measurement there will be `nan`

```
t=[0 3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24];
x=[1 2 3 4 5 NaN NaN 20 22];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ismember`, or better still `ismembertol` because [we're dealing with floating point numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab), to get the index of each member of `t` within your uniform-interval `tNew` and then fill in the corresponding values of `x`:

```
tNew = 0:3:24;                      % Make new uniform-interval array for time
xNew = NaN(size(tNew));             % Initialise x to all NaN
[~,idx] = ismembertol(t,tNew,1e-6); % Find the index of each t in tNew within tolerance
xNew(idx) = x;                      % Assign values of x to xNew at the same indices
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```matlab
dt=min(diff(t))
t1=t(1):dt:t(end);
temp=setdiff(t1,t);
for i=1:numel(temp)
    x=[x(1:(temp(i)-t(1))/dt),NaN,x((temp(i)-t(1))/dt+1:end)];
end
```

The main thing you need to look out for is whether `t(end)` would be a valid entry based on constant `dt`. From the sound of it, all entries are always valid except that some may be missing, in which case the above code should suffice.

If your data set is very large, you may want to initialize a new vector of the right length and use the above indices as a reference to check against for how to populate the "filled" data vector.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thing is *exactly* what MATLAB's [`timetable`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/timetables.html?s_tid=CRUX_lftnav) and [`retime`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timetable.retime.html) are designed for.

First, you need to make a timetable by converting `t` to a `duration` using the [`seconds`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/duration.seconds.html?s_tid=doc_ta) function.

```matlab
tt = timetable(seconds(t'), x');
```

Note `table` and `timetable` both deal with columns of data.

Then, we can simply use `retime` specifying that want to retime to a regular timestep, using the `'fillwithmissing'` option, like this:

```matlab
>> retime(tt, 'regular', 'fillwithmissing', 'TimeStep', seconds(3))
ans =
  9x1 timetable
     Time     Var1
    ______    ____

    0 sec       1 
    3 sec       2 
    6 sec       3 
    9 sec       4 
    12 sec      5 
    15 sec    NaN 
    18 sec    NaN 
    21 sec     20 
    24 sec     22
```